# Unable to play videos on 22.04 LTS

Tags: video, vlc, mp4

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 back in June and was able to play mp4 as well as flv files without any issues. Suddenly about two weeks ago, I'm unable to play those files either using the default "Videos" app or VLC Media Player. No other apps have been installed prior to this new problem. If I double click an mp4 file, it opens up for a second and then vanishes without showing an error message. If I open the videos app directly, it crashes. If I right click an mp4 and choose VLC, nothing happens at all. Same thing when I start VLC directly. I was advised to install restricted extras as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

This had no effect. I'm ready to wipe the hard disk and reinstall Ubuntu, but I'd rather not. Kindly Help!

Comment: Has there been a kernel update between when it worked and when it stopped working?

Comment: David: Probably. I don't closely track the Ubuntu updates. I just obediently click the install button.

Comment: Often they ask you for a password, ring a bell?

Comment: Yes about the password. Maybe 1 out of 5 times, but I don't recall if a kernel update marked the beginning of the problem.

Comment: OK based on your info my only guess was kernel upgrade.

Comment: Is it typical for a kernel upgrade to wreck functions this way?

Comment: If the video driver is in the kernel yes an update can have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

meanwhile have you used vlc codecs

```
$ sudo apt install vlc
$ sudo apt update
```

and if you can share the screenshot of specific error(keep in mind, blur you user name before sharing it. Even the time zone)

Comment: VLC was already installed, probably via the Ubuntu Software app (I don't recall). So, using sudo apt install vlc added a second instance and it works! But why does it work?

Comment: One may be snap, the new one. The other may be an apt install hence it looks like you have 2.

Comment: snap updates can also be run but if you have heavy ram like 4 gb or 6gb  8gb something then go for Gnome player it has the capability to run subtitles and changing the audio stream option to another language or even saving the video in another formats .............

Comment: It's more of a comment than an answer really.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem of .mkv files (with AAC audio codec+H.264 video codec in it) recorded using OBS studio, were not playing in any of the players , not even in vlc player. I recently installed latest version of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my old lenovo IdeaPad with Intel+nvidia integrated Optimus GPU.
Then I just ran this command, and then after these files started playing perfectly

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Hoping this helps someone out there.